Minimum Distance between a Point and a Point on Line in $\mathbb{C}^2$: Does the Perpendicularity Condition Hold?
Sorry if this seems too easy, I am not quite sure where to look for the relevant knowledge, proofs, and derivations needed for this problem.
So on $\mathbb{R}^2$, say we have vector $a=\left(x_1,\ y_1\right)$ and $b=\left(x_2,\ y_2\right)$, we can define $a\cdot b=x_1x_2+y_1y_2$, and $\left|a\right|=\sqrt{a\cdot a}$. And this conclusion should be quite trivial: Let there be a line $l:y=kx+h$ where $x,y,k,h\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $a\notin l$ and $b\in l$. Then we have this apparent statement: $\left|a-b\right|$ reaches its minimum iff $\forall c\in l$ we have $\left(a-b\right)\cdot\left(b-c\right)=0$.
Or, in English, point $A$ outside of line $l$, $B$ on line $l$, distance between $A$ and $B$ is minimum iff $AB\perp l$.
And now my problem is, does the same conclusion hold true for $\mathbb{C}^2$?
We know that for $\mathbb{C}^2$, it is defined that $a\cdot b=x_1\bar{x_2}+y_1\bar{y_2}$, and the norm of a vector is still $\left|a\right|=\sqrt{a\cdot a}$. Can we still say that $\left|a-b\right|$ reaches its minimum iff $\forall c\in l$ we have $\left(a-b\right)\cdot\left(b-c\right)=0$?
And if so, how do I prove it?

Replace the steps of your proof: instead of having an inner product you have a hermitian product

To add to what @julio_es_sui_glace wrote, one could notice that $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a Hilbert space, and then what you're looking for is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Properties (see "Best approximation")

Thank you! The term "Hilbert Projection Theorem" solved me problem. It's exactly that. I'm looking into the proof of that theorem.
